# <%=%> vs <%%> in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form in ruby html:

```
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :text %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

---

**Attention**

The last line of code:`<% end %>`, why it is not `<%= end %>`?

whats the different function with them? and if use `<%= end %>`, there will get this [syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379862/rails-syntax-unexpected-keyword-do-block).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<% %>` will evaluate the code, but will not print the output.

`<%= %>` will evaluate the code AND print the output.